# asp.net webapi 2.0 handle wrong route

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have developed an API for an application and i have all routes set up, but when the users request the wrong action, the server returns 404 by default and i tried to find some way of changing that but i didnt find anything...

So lets say i have an api with the following route:

```
/api/school/1/classes
```

if the client requests

```
/api/school/1/classez
```

i want to return response code 501 or 405 instead of the default 404.
how can this be done?

Comment: It makes sense to have a 404 when you request a resource that doesn't exist. A 405 means method not allowed which is not the same thing. 501 errors are not something you typically see and may confuse the client as to why their request didn't work.

Comment: Do you want to return 501 for all 404? Or just in some cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Route attributes.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/{id}/foo")]
public HttpResponseMessage foo(int id)
{
    var response = new ApiResponse();
    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    return response;
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("api/{id}/{route}")]
public HttpResponseMessage bar(int id)
{
    var response = new ApiResponse();
    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
    return response;
}
```

If they type it correctly then it will enter foo.  Otherwise they will enter bar and you can handle that how ever you like.